# ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer "Django"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-requests, serversocket

I facing connection error issue on my server .  I dont know what's causing them as this problem arises for no particular reason.  Whenever it arises all the requests get halted but all the request get through after few minutes. I am guessing it is happening because of the threading process I am using for uploading files(may be , not sure) .  Any help regarding this is much appreciated. Here is the error I am facing . Thanks

```
Exception occurred during processing of request from ('0.0.0.7', 23266)
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/socketserver.py", line 683, in process_request_thread
web_1  |     self.finish_request(request, client_address)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
web_1  |     self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/socketserver.py", line 747, in __init__
web_1  |     self.handle()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
web_1  |     self.handle_one_request()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 179, in handle_one_request
web_1  |     self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 704, in readinto
web_1  |     return self._sock.recv_into(b)
web_1  | ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: How are you calling the endpoint? This error usually happens when the connection on client (FE) closes (times out or something).

Comment: @ToniSredanović I am calling the endpoint through DRF

Comment: Do you have gunicorn setup in a server ?? Sometimes issues may cause due to gunicorn too.

Comment: Alright, but which client are u using? Postman, curl, ajax, ...?

Comment: @ToniSredanović I am using Postman as well as curl. basically, I am running this as an android app and using django and django rest framework as backend

Comment: @SuryaBista I thought of that too, thats why I stopped gunicorn from the backend but the problem still arises randomly

Comment: @ToniSredanović I am using retrofit2 on android side to call the end points